# Does Twitter update Tweet_ID

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, tweepy

I'm scraping data using tweepy module in python and storing tweets in MYSQL DB.
Later I'm fetching these tweets and loading twitter widgets.

After few days when I scrape for the same Handle, I see that for few tweets tweet ID is getting changed and due to this reason twitter widgets won't load.

Does twitter update tweet id??
  If so, do they follow any particular interval for updation.

Comment: Can you give an example? Twitter IDs shouldn't change.

Comment: @TerenceEden Below is one of the tweet whose id has changed. 
old id (Scraped on 21-3-2017) - 822457454147620864, when data scraped again on 29-3-2017 the same id changed to 822457454147620866 (verified based on text of the tweet), below is the link to the post.
https://twitter.com/IndiainAngola/status/822457454147620866

Comment: What code are you using to get the ID? Are you using `id_str`? Twitter doesn't change the IDs - so it is probably a mistake with your code.

Comment: @TerenceEden I'm using id_str itself

Comment: Let's see your code.

Comment: Here's a link to current code which I'm using to scrape a handle's tweets

Comment: You haven't included a link. Edit your original post to show your code.

Comment: @TerenceEden Here's a link to current code which I'm using to scrape a handle's tweets
http://pythonfiddle.com/twitter-scraper

I'm using this scraper and creating data frame, and updating DB.

Comment: Twitter IDs don't change. Your code looks fine. I would guess you have a problem with your database. How are you storing the numbers? Bear in mind that Twitter uses 64 bit snowflake IDs.